# Prim's algorithm using heap or unsorted array?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, prism, minimum-spanning-tree

There's a question in my CS class asking that if the graph is a sparse graph, which is n^2 >> m, whether unsorted list with O(n^2) is more efficient than the binary heap O((m+n)logn). I'm a little bit confused with this one because I thought (m+n)logn is always better than n^2. Can anyone give some insights on this?

Comment: m (the number of edges) varies from 0 to approximately n^2/2. You can see if m is small enough (ie: the graph is sparse enough) then (m+n)log n is better than n^2, and if m is large enough (ie: the graph is dense enough) then (m+n)log n is worse than n^2.

Comment: Hi @Elon, please let me know if the explanation below was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> a dense graph is a graph in which the number of edges is close to the maximal number of edges. The opposite, a graph with only a few edges, is a sparse graph.

from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_graph).

Suppose we have a *sparse graph* with `n` nodes and `m` edges. Time complexity of the *Prim's Algorithm* is `O( (n + m) log(n))` if we use a binary heap data structure. If we use an unsorted array (assuming you meant an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix#:%7E:text=In%20graph%20theory%20and%20computer,with%20zeros%20on%20its%20diagonal.)), then it becomes `O(n^2)` as you stated.

Compare the time complexities: `O((n + m)log(n))` and `O(n^2)`.

If our graph is *sparse*, then `n > m`. Therefore `n^2 > mlog(n)`, which means that it's a better idea to implement the algorithm with a binary heap rather than an adjacency matrix.

If we have a *dense* graph, then we can at most `m = n*(n-1)` number of edges for a [simple graph](http://www.people.vcu.edu/%7Egasmerom/MAT131/graphs.html#:%7E:text=A%20simple%20graph%20is%20a,edge%20(arc)%20connecting%20them.). 
It means that `n^2 < mlog(n) ~ n^2 log(n)`. Therefore, now it's logical to use an adjacency matrix. If our graph is not simple, then there may be more than one edges between two nodes - therefore we can have more than `n* (n-1)` edges.
 However, the distinction between sparse and dense graphs is rather vague, and depends on the context. Therefore it's not guarantee that in a *dense graph* we will have `m >= n*(n-1)` number of nodes.